# What's the cardinality of this set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

let $A_K= \{ a\in \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}} \mid \sum_{100k}^{100k +99}a_i=200 \}$. and let $A=\cap^\infty_{k=1}A_k$. 
What is the cardinality of $A$? 

I can't think of how to figure this out, the intersection bugs me alot, I am not able to understand what will $A$ be like? 
Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will consider $\mathbb{N} = \{0, 1, 2, \dots \}.$If I understand correctly, we consider $\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ as a direct product and define the sets $A_k,$ which are the sets of all sequences of natural numbers such that the sum of the elements on positions $100 k$ through $100 k + 99$ is exactly $200$ (thus the sum of certain $100$ elements of the sequence is $200$).

We would want to determine how many elements of $\mathbb{N}^{100}$ satisfy the condition that the sum of their elements is exactly $200.$ Let us denote $b \in \mathbb{N}^{100}$ as $b = (b_1, b_2, \dots, b_{100}).$ Let $n_k := \# B_k,$ where $B_k := \{b \in \mathbb{N}^{100}: \sum_{1 \leq j \leq 100} b_j = k\}.$ Clearly, $n_1 = 100.$ Moreover, any sequence $b \in B_{k + 1}$ can be obtained from a sequence in $c \in B_k$ by adding $1$ to one of the elements $c_j, \, 1 \leq j \leq 100.$ There are usually many ways to do this (depending on the number of non-zero elements of $b \in B_{k + 1}$) and counting the exact number would be pretty tedious. However, it is not hard to see that $n_k \leq n_{k + 1} \leq 100 n_k$ (the lower bound is obtained by the previous remark, the one about adding a $1$ on a certain position and the upper one follows from the fact that the number of ways we can add a $1$ to an element $c \in B_k$ to obtain a fixed element $b \in B_{k + 1}$ is at most $100$ since these entities themselves have exactly $100$ positions). Thus, $100 = n_1 \leq n_{200} \leq 100^{200} n_0 = 100^{200}.$ It follows that there are injections $\mathbb{100} \hookrightarrow B_{200} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{100^{200}}$ (where by $\mathbb{n}$ i denote a set with $n$ elements).

Then $A := \bigcap_{k \geq 0} A_k$ is the set of all sequences of natural numbers such that the sum of the elements with indices $100 k$ through $100 k + 99$ is exactly 200. Note that $A \simeq \prod_{k \in \mathbb{N}} B_{200} = B_{200}^\mathbb{N}.$ It follows that there are injections $\mathbb{100^N} \hookrightarrow A \hookrightarrow (\mathbb{100^{200}})^\mathbb{N}.$ However, we know that $\mathbb{n}^\mathbb{N}$ has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N},$ so it follows from an immediate application of *Cantor-Bernstein-Schroder* that the cardinality of $A$ is $2^{\aleph_0}.$ Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: For each $S\subseteq\Bbb N$ define a sequence $a^S\in\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}$ as follows: for each $k\in\Bbb N$,

$$\begin{align*}
a_{100k}^S&=\begin{cases}
200,&\text{if }k\notin S\,,\\
0,&\text{if }k\in S
\end{cases}\\\\
a_{100k+1}^S&=\begin{cases}
0,&\text{if }k\in S\\
200,&\text{if }k\notin S\,,\text{ and}
\end{cases}\\\\
a_{100k+\ell}^S&=0\text{ for }\ell=2,\ldots,99\,.
\end{align*}$$

- Show that $a^S\in A$ for each $S\subseteq\Bbb N$.
- Show that the map $\wp(\Bbb N)\to\Bbb N^{\Bbb N}:S\mapsto a^S$ is a bijection.

From this you should be able to determine the cardinality of $A$.